# como construir dos consultas a la misma tabla en una sola

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Tengo esta tabla con estas dos consultas
pero no encuentro la manera de mostrar las dos consultas en una sola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado final debe mostrarse asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que la **Query 1** se explica por sí sola. Se trata de sumar en un case solamente los revisados.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cf187/8)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE revisor
    (`id_proyecto` varchar(4), `id_revisor` varchar(20), `revisado` int)
;

INSERT INTO revisor
    (`id_proyecto`, `id_revisor`, `revisado`)
VALUES
    ('b123', 'José',  0),
    ('b123', 'Pedro', 1),
    ('b123', 'Pablo', 0),
    ('a123', 'José',  0),
    ('a123', 'Pedro', 1),
    ('a123', 'Pablo', 1),
    ('a123', 'Pérez', 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  id_proyecto, count(*) TotalRevisores, 
  sum(case when revisado = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as revisados
FROM
  revisor
GROUP BY id_proyecto
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cf187/8/0)**:

```
| id_proyecto | TotalRevisores | revisados |
|-------------|----------------|-----------|
|        a123 |              4 |         3 |
|        b123 |              3 |         1 |
```

Comment: Eres un master amigo gracias me salvaste soy noob en esto

Comment: De nada. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Si quieres puedes también votar la respuesta positivamente, flecha gris apuntando hacia arriba a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción sería: Usando la union de tus consultas, y agregando una columna con valor cero.

```
select id_proyecto, 
       sum(totalRevisores) totalRevisores, 
       sum(Revisados) Revisados 
  from ( select id_proyecto, count(*) totalRevisores, 0 Revisados 
              from Revisor group by id_proyecto 
   union select id_proyecto, 0 totalRevisores, count(*) Revisados 
              from Revisor where revisado = 1 group by id_proyecto ) 
    tbaux group by 1
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda lo tomare en cuenta